# How to Load Ubuntu Core "Snap" as custom image on MAAS?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I'd like to upload on my MaaS server (ppa stable) the image of Ubuntu Core ("Snappy") to try it and provision new nodes using that custom image.

I tested Snappy in a KVM environment and now I'd like to test it in my Lab.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snappy is an entirely new architecture. Currently, MAAS installs an ephemeral image on the node, which in turn installs the actual OS using `curtin`. We are working on integrating snappy semantics in `curtin`, so that `curtin` is able to lay down a snappy image. That's why you don't see any snappy images available in MAAS. Please stay tuned to the mailers!

Comment: any news about that?